# How to make a Flutter appliction a daemon in Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, cron, daemon

So, I have a flutter application. It works great, but it needs to do some background API calls. My current implementation is to turn off the gui, by not running the widget classes if there are command line arguments. Here's my main, to show what I am talking about:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  //if no args passed, GUI MODE
  if (args.isEmpty) {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }
  //if there are command line args, GUI-Less mode
  else {
    String input = args[0];
    //weather api call that writes a json to a file
    weather(input);
  }
}
```

This works fine on Windows' task scheduler. However, trying to do the same thing in Ubuntu's crontab I have hit a major snag. Flutter applications seem always open a window on Ubuntu, even if no widgets are used. The code doesn't execute if it can't open a display I noticed. If I set DISPLAY=:0, then the code works but every time the background call happens user sees a random blank window appear which defeats the point of what I am trying to do.

I'm not sure how to disable this behavior of Flutter or make it play nice with the crontab without popping up a window every time a background API call needs to happen. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

tl;dr

I've tried to make a GUI-less version of a Flutter application to run as a daemon in Ubuntu via crontab. I expected the application to run silently in the background and do the scheduled api call. What actually happened is Flutter always opens a window, which requires the display variable to be set in crontab to function properly. However, that causes a blank window to appear for every background API call.

Comment: Isn't a "gui-less" Flutter program a Dart command line program?

Comment: I'm going to preface this comment with I figured out a solution using: "xvfb" to give a dummy display.

But yes, this is why I thought it could be done through Flutter since Dart could do it. 
The Flutter GUI uses a lot of code the daemon would use. A solution would be to duplicate the part of the code I need and put in its own dart project and compile it as an exe to be used on the Ubuntu platform only. I didn't like the fact I was duplicating code or creating another parallel codebase that needs to be maintained and updated.

Comment: Just put all the common code in a separate package. If that happens to be Dart only, you can even add the Dart command line code as a file in \bin (of the default package folder structure)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve the problem by using 'xvfb'.To my understanding it gives the Flutter executable a dummy display allowing it to execute the rest of the code.

xvfb can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

This is what it looks like in the crontab:

```
* * * * * xvfb-run -a /.../flutterapp.exe flutterAppArgs
```

This seems to work so far. Whether this is ideal or not, I'm honestly not sure but it at least works.